# how to remove only one url of origin

Tags: git

I have a git repo set up with three url:s like this

```
origin https://github.com... (fetch)
origin https://github.com... (push)
origin https://...@bitbucket.org... (push)
```

Now I want to change only the bitbucket-url, but I only find a git command to remove an entire group (in my case origin) but that's not what I want.

Morover, I suspect my setup is wrong, the bitbucket, "backup-repo" I am pushing to should probably be set up as something else than "origin" right?

Comment: How did you get two different remotes with the same name? You were must get the error, something like `fatal: remote origin already exists.`

Comment: Remove and readd, then. Or edit `.git/config` manually--it's just an ini-style text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you shouldn't have `origin` point to two different URLs for push. Instead, you should have a different remote for one of those uses.

You can add a remote to point to Bitbucket with something like:

```
$ git remote add bitbucket https://...@bitbucket.org...
```

As to how to remove just one of those, I'm not sure if there's a convenient command for it, but just editing `.git/config` should be sufficient; it is just a plain text file in a fairly simple format. You will probably have a section that looks like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://...@bitbucket.org...
    push = ...
```

Just delete that and you shouldn't have the extra remote pointing to Bitbucket.

Answer (score 0):

As Brian notes, problem can be solved by directly editing .git folder contents. But that is not necessary. You can reset the origin to normal state with usual Git commands:

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin https://github.com...
```

Or you may want to give it a new name now:

```
git remote add github https://github.com...
```

Add bitbucket as new separate remote

```
git remote add bitbucket https://...@bitbucket.org...
```